# It is good practice to use threads(c# winforms) to improve performance for a matrix style application?

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, microsoft-dynamics

i am creating a matrix style application. It is a controlAddIn for Microsoft Dynamics Nav 2013. Basically i create lots of textboxes inside panels. So i have rows and columns and the cells that are cross by them(see picture below).[image]

I have no idea how to improve the performance when the number of controls is getting bigger. There is a way to liberate space or memory or just prevent to get a faildown??

I looked to use dispose(), Controls.Clear() ... but still gets some problems, and crushes Dynamics NAV...

Microsoft Dynamics Nav uses the .dll that i get from generating my proyect. It interacts with the database with 8 functions that get call from DynamicsNav. And everytime i do and event, like click i called EventControlAddIn, and clears all the controls Inside a mainpanel and regenerates everything... So the problem is when i got lots of controls it take a while...

I thought of doing multiples threads, but i never use this and still a little raw on the subject, so any ideas will be welcome

Thanks for any help

Comment: Its good practice to use threads for retrieving or calculating data. It is not for showing data. If you have problems because of repainting many controls replace your selfmade grid with a real grid control and see if the behavior changes.

Comment: 'lots' how many is lots?... "a while" how long is a while?

Comment: I will try with gridview or tablelayoutPanel @Ralf.

Comment: Lots is 15x20 and while is 3 to 5 seconds(or it gets dynamics nav to fail and close himself)... @PaulZahra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method to improve performance would be to reuse the controls which you are using inside the matrix so at all times you would have active only NxM controls where N is the height and M is the width of the matrix( the visible region of the data ).

Depending on the data you might want to use async operations to prevent UI lagging. Generally it's a good practice to implement async data retrieval so that when the user waits for the information to appear on the matrix they won't have to wait for all of it to appear, rather the information will be updated as it comes.

If you really want great performance you might want to implement your own Data grid by deriving from    System.Windows.Forms.Control and implement all the rendering logic yourself.